# SQLAlchemy Joined Table Inheritance: Problem adding objects

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, sqlalchemy

I'm having problems trying to add inherited objects with SQLAlchemy following the instructions in https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/inheritance.html to implement **Joined Table Inheritance**.

I'm using a PostgreSQL version 14 as a database engine.

Here is my **Base** configuration:

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base

db_string = os.environ['DB_STRING']

engine = create_engine(db_string)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
Base = automap_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
```

Here is  **Instrument** (parent class) definition:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column,  String
from context_model.database import Base


class Instrument(Base):
    __tablename__ = "instrument"

    _id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    discriminator = Column(String)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'instrument',
        'polymorphic_on': discriminator
```

Here is **Bond** (child class) definition:

```
import datetime as dt

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Float, String, DateTime, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from context_model.instrument.instrument import Instrument


class Bond(Instrument):
    __tablename__ = "bond"

    _id = Column(String, ForeignKey("instrument._id"), primary_key=True)
    _provider_bbg_id = Column(String)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'bond'
    }
```

When I try to add a **Bond** instance and persist it to the database:

```
Bond = Base.classes.bond
bond = Bond()
bond._id = "0"
bond._provider_bbg_id = "XXX"
db_session.add(bond)
db_session.commit()
```

appears the following error message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation) insert or update on table "bond" violates foreign key constraint "bond__id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (_id)=(0) is not present in table "instrument"."
```

It seems to me that the inheritance is not working for some reason, did I define well the **Instrument** (parent) and **Bond** (child) classes ?, maybe do I need to use another type of Base ? (I'm using **automap_base** )

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: +1 for your comment. When I see PG, and inheritance - I have one idea :) Anyway 
 - your `Bond` has -  `_id = Column(String, ForeignKey("instrument._id"), primary_key=True)` - underscore breaks connection. For me, without that - works :)

Comment: With respect to `Base`, it's most common to use `orm.declarative_base()`, `automap_base()` being for cases where you want to generate models from existing tables in a database.  It's not clear whether you are reflecting existing tables or creating your own, new, tables.

Comment: Thank you very much! I changed from declarative_base to automap_base and now works :). The problem was not related with "underscores" @MichalZaborowski, anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact reasons but I changed from `declarative_base()` to `automap_base()` as @snakecharmerb suggested in the commentaries and now it works :)